# How to store Android Log entry as a string

Tags: android, logcat, android-log

I can't seem to find an answer or a question regarding this:

How do I store an Android Log entry to a string:

```
Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: start: ");

String s = /* get last Log entry */.toString();
```

The reason for this is so I can have the process ID and thread IDs. When I try to manual store the process and thread IDs, the thread IDs are different than printed in Logcat:

```
Log.i(TAG, "#checkWifiConnection: start");
String s = Integer.toString(android.os.Process.myPid()) + " " + Integer.toString(android.os.Process.getThreadPriority(android.os.Process.myTid())) + " " + TAG;
System.out.println(s + "#checkWifiConnection: start");
```

Logcat shows:

```
01-09 18:38:02.994 1558-2021 I/*~FETCH DATA: #checkWifiConnection: start
```

System.out shows:

```
I/System.out: 1558 10 *~FETCH DATA#checkWifiConnection: start
```

Comment: I don't think the Log class should work as a cache system to do what you want. You can save whatever you need in other ways.

Comment: you can read the android log with adb like `adb shell logcat` but it's an output firehose. What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I store an Android Log entry to a string

You can not do this.

From [`Log documentation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log)

> Generally, you should use the Log.v(), Log.d(), Log.i(), Log.w(), and Log.e() methods to write logs. You can then view the logs in logcat.

They are only for `Logcat` in `debug` section, so I recommend you to look for another way to store your desire.

For instance you could create a class, that stores all of the `Log` you have, and then store it wherever you want.

> I already know how to store some information into a seperate class but the reason I wanted Log.toString was for the time stamps, process IDs, and thread IDs

Then create more attributes for this specific class and pass them whenever you want.

To store the `Process id` use

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
```

To store the `Thread id` use

```
int tid = android.os.Process.getThreadPriority(android.os.Process.myTid());
```

To store the timestamp use

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
String format = s.format(new Date());
```

Comment: I already know how to store some information into a seperate class but the reason I wanted Log.toString was for the time stamps, process IDs, and thread IDs

Comment: Then create a class that have these params and send it

Comment: This does not report the correct thread ID. At least it's not the same as the logcat.

Comment: I've tested it and it's the same number, could you provide your code to see why is not the same for you?

Comment: Can you try this `Process.myTid()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible to do that however you could make your own object which handles log calls and sets a string instance variable to the last message. You can then retrieve this string from the object